# add button to bootstrap modal footer dynamically by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a button dynamically to the footer of a bootstrap modal.
Is that possible? Can't find it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRead" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body"><p id="myModalBody"></p>
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer"  id="myModalFooter" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

for example this button:

```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-ok"
> data-dismiss="modal">Delete or whatever</button>
```

jquery:

```
 jQuery(function($) {       
$("#myModalBody").html(text);           
$("#myModalRead").modal('show');
    });
```

kind of

> $("#myModalFooter").addabutton();

Comment: Yes, it's possible in various ways, like [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thank you!  $( "#myModalFooter" ).append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" >Delete</button>' ); works perfectly